# setting a variable with jquery data

Tags: jquery, jquery-data

I'm trying to make a variable in a function, that I can then redefine using it again in a different function, and I was wanting to use jquery .data to do it but am unsure how.

I have this

```
$(".photo").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

in the next function I'd like to redefine the id variable...using the previous id variable value, any ideas on how to do this?

```
$("#next").click(function() {  
  var id = $(id).next().attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer is global variables, so it ended up being like this:

```
$(".photo").click(function() {
    id = $(this).attr('id');
});

$("#next").click(function() {  
      var id_a = $('#' + id).next().attr('id');
      id = id_a;
});

$("#prev").click(function() {  
      var id_b = $('#' + id).prev().attr('id');
      id = id_b;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define new common variable for both functions as @loriensleafs's answer.

Additionally, i recommend using Closure for prevent scope issue.

```
(function() {
    var id;    // common value but canb be accessed only in this function.

    $(".button").click(function() {
        id = $(this).attr('id');
    });

    $("#output").click(function() {  
        $("p").css( "background", "none" );
        $("div").find('#' + id).css( "background", "red" );
    });
})();
```

check http://jsfiddle.net/cwdoh/G2RjH/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to define that variable `globally` so other function can use it.

**Sample Tested Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        var GlobalScope;

        $('#boxes').click(function()
        {
            GlobalScope = $.trim($(this).html());
        });

        $('#boxes_').click(function()
        {
            console.log(GlobalScope);
        });
    });

</script>

<div id="boxes">
    One
</div>

<div id="boxes_">
    Two
</div>
```

When you click on boxes it will set `GlobalScope` variable value as `One` now after click `boxes` when you click on `boxes_` `GlobalScope` value will be `One` in `Console.log`.